# Is this sentence correct "Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood get mixed with water"?

Tags: grammar

My book has this form for this sentence **Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood, getting mixed with water.** and also **Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood, to get mixed with water.** But I wrote *Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood get mixed with water.* It will be very helpful if someone explain why one is incorrect and the others are correct.

This is a text book sentence which has **When rain and flood wash away chemicals, it gets mixed with water.(make is simple)**

Comment: None of the three are really correct or idiomatic. As usual, context is key. What is this book and what is it trying to say?

Comment: This is my text book which has the cimplex form of that sentence and wants to change it into simple.

Comment: My book and my textbook, which is it??

Comment: Textbook."Young learner's communicative English."

Comment: This sentence is wrong/unusual on many levels. It is not idiomatic to use “flood” to refer to water directly. We more often think of a “flood” as an event. The waters that result from the “flood” are called “flood waters” and this is what might be washing away chemicals. So, if this was a real sentence in a real book I’d expect it to say, “Chemicals are mixed with water when they are washed away by rain and flood waters.”

Comment: If that is the correct sentence then can you please give the simple form of it?

Comment: @Orbital Aussie This may be a difference between Australian and American English, but "flood" used this way is perfectly idiomatic in the US. "As the snow melts, flood is an ever-present danger in these mountain valleys."  "Fire, flood, and famine killed thousands." Perfectly good English here. Of course maybe in Australia you cannot say "The flood destroyed the town" and must say "The flood waters destroyed the town," but that is not true in the US.

Comment: @JeffMorrow. No, I’m sorry, I may not have communicated this well.  I do indeed fully agree with you - each of your examples work in both American and Australian usage. But notice that in each of your sentences you refer to “flood” as an event.(eg: “The flood destroyed the town.”) But consider instead: “The cleanup was horrendous. We even found flood inside the fridge.” This is refers to water directly (not an event) and so it doesn’t work. You have to say, “We even found floodwater inside the fridge.”

Comment: @Orbital Aussie OK. US and Australia seem to be on the same page or almost the same page. "Flood" and "flood waters" have overlapping but not identical fields of meaning. I absolutely agree with you about your fridge example. Where we may disagree is between "rain and flood wash" and "rain and flood water wash." I find both grammatical. I prefer the first because of parallelism, and I find "rain water and flood water" both pedantic and verbose. Still, it is not worth fighting about. That is not where the OP was having a question.

Comment: @JeffMorrow. Yes, we are in agreement. I was more focused on “chemicals are washed away by rain and flood”.

Comment: @Ghost. Perhaps a better way to rephrase your sentence (taking into account Jeff Morrow’s valid questions regarding my first comment) might be this: **“Chemicals are mixed with water when they are washed away by rain and flood.”** But this version, taking us much further from your original sentence, would be the way I might have expressed it: “Chemicals are mixed with water when it rains or in a flood.”

Answer (score 2):

Both forms in your text are grammatical although the second is poorly punctuated and not very idiomatic.

The first form

> Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood, [thereby] mixing chemicals with water

is quite idiomatic, with or without the ellipsis.

> Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood to mix chemicals with water

is grammatical but not idiomatic because it is likely to be read as

> Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood [in order] to mix chemicals with water

which is not the intended meaning.

Your sentence is not grammatical because it has two verbs. It could be made grammatical as

> Chemicals are washed away by rain and flood **and** [thereby] get mixed with water

or

> Chemicals **that** are washed away by rain and flood get mixed with water

Some ways that I would simplify the given sentence are:

> Chemicals that are washed away by rain and flood mix with the water
>
> Chemicals that are washed away by rain and flood dissolve in the water
>
> Chemicals that are washed away by rain and flood contaminate the water

You could also use a participial phrase as an ellipsis for the clause in the passive, *e.g.*

> Chemicals washed away by rain and flood mix with the water